# Can I do this floor exercise routine every day?

Tags: bodyweight-exercises

**Question:** Can I perform the workout listed below every day without worrying about injury or should I take a break every couple of days?

```
=========================
jumping jacks (1 min)
Squats (30 sec)
Calf Raises (30 sec)
Standing Steam Engines (30 sec)
Pushups (30 sec)
Rest (30 sec)
Toe Touches (on back) (30 sec)
Front Plank pushups (30 sec)
Front Plank (30 sec)
Supermans (30 sec)
Pike Pushups (30 sec)
Rest (30 sec)
Bridges (30 sec)
Bicycle Crunches (30 sec)
Side Plank (L) (30 sec)
Side Plank (R) (30 sec)
Wide Pushups (30 sec)
Jumping Jacks (1 min)
=======================
```

Thank you for your insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been doing this exact routine daily for over 8 months. I found it in a video, memorized and didn't miss a day since I started; I did not observe adverse effects and I believe I gained a little strength/endurance out of it.

It got really easy relatively quick, so I extend it proportionally to 15 or 20 minutes.

My limit used to be around 30 pushups before I lost stamina and form. I can now do 50 decent pushups in ~45 seconds.

Comment: I really appreciate the testimonial to your experience with it. It is really helpful. I have been extending the workout now by doing it twice a day, keeping the time the same.

Answer (score 2):

Whether you can do this every day will really depend on what condition you're initially in, but if you're fit enough to do the workout without feeling sore the next day, then yes, there's no reason why you couldn't do it every day. But conversely, it's only 10 minutes of exercise with no progression (increase in difficulty) built into it, so you'll find that after a very short period it will become too easy to be of any benefit to you.